# How to update label in Form1 from Class?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, label, invoke

I'm trying to update `Label` which is in `Form1` obviously and it `count good proxies`, if there is a exception thrown it `count bad proxies`.
The `Sub` which `invoke` this labels are in `Form1`, the method is called from `Class1` so I declared `Frm as Form1` but it doesn't invoke and doesn't update labels =+1

I read many similar examples here on forum but I'm not sure what is the solution for me, I want to keep the code for proxies in Class1 if I move it to the Form1 then it works btw.

**My Class1:**

```
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Class1
    Public Shared Property Frm As Form1
    Public Shared _Count As Integer
    Public Shared Sub GetProxies()

        While True
            Try
                'MY CODE 


                Interlocked.Increment(_Count)
                Frm.GoodProxyCount()

            Catch ex As Exception
                Frm.OnBadRequestChanged()
            End Try

        End While
        Properties._runningThreads.Remove(Thread.CurrentThread)
    End Sub
End Class
```

**My Form1 Sub methods:**

```
Public Class Form1
    Public Sub OnBadRequestChanged()
            Try
                If Me.lblProxies.Text > 0 Then
                    Me.Invoke(Sub() Me.lblProxies.Text -= 1)
                Else
                    If Not Me.chkManualProxies.Checked Then
                        Me.btnScrapeStart()
                    End If
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try
        End Sub
    
        Public Sub GoodProxyCount()
            Try
                Me.Invoke(Sub() Me.lbl_count.Text = Class1._Count.ToString())
    
                If Me.lblProxies.Text > 0 Then
                    Me.Invoke(Sub() Me.lblProxies.Text -= 1)
                Else
                    If Not Me.chkManualProxies.Checked Then
                        Me.btnScrapeStart()
                    End If
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try
        End Sub
 End Class
```

I have the same problem with anything I try to update like `frm.checkbox.checked` or other radiobuttons impossible to update or populate `listview` from outside of the Form1 so I don't know what am I missing here some declaration or property??

thanks for help

Comment: You need to create an instance of Form1 then set Class1.Frm equal to that instance.

Comment: Guessing your dabbling in threading here, hence why trying to do the invokes.  your approch seems a little out of whack though.  So if not doing this by threading, you've got a couple options.  Pass the instance of your form through to the class, update the access modifiers on your labels then it's simply frm.label1.Text = ... inside the class or return a result collection from your class method that you parse and display in your form.  If using a background worker, you can leverage the ReportProcess and Complete methods of the bgw to transfer info

Comment: @Vasya I have made it please look Public Shared Property Frm As Form1

Comment: Does your app START with Form1? If so, in the `Load()` event of Form1 add this line of code: `Class1.Frm = Me`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer for someone who struggle with the same issue so do follow:

1. Add this declaration line in the top of your Form1 Class:

`Public Shared instance As Form1`

3. Declare a Label or CheckBox etc.. what you wish to 'invoke or access' from other class or forms as follows:

`Public txt_Title As Label`

4. Note that you have to give other name as the real name what is in your Form1, for example my **TITLE LABEL** is called: `txtTitle` but I had to change the name something I remember and similar in this declaration.
5. Create Sub in Form1 as Follows:

   Public Sub Instances()
   instance = Me
   txt_Title = txtTitle
   End Sub
6. Initialize the Sub in Form1_Load as follows:

   ```
   Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
      Try
     Instances()
      Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
    End Sub
   ```
7. NOW from the Class1 just call any Label or elements you declared in Form1 as follows:

Form1.instance.txt_Title .Text = "me desired text from Class1"

I hope it helps someone as I struggle like 2 days on this since I'm self educated coder and I code for fun I could not known this as this is for someone basics from school btw..

Comment: You could have done it in one line of code if you used my comment. No need to have those two variables declared in Form1. Just the original Form1 reference in the other Class that you update...

Comment: @Idle_Mind sure I know but I already did it but I will try your suggestion since it is easiest to avoid more declaration if many elements. Thanks for your time to answer btw I appreciate

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Class1 still has the Shared variable to reference a Form1:

```
Public Class Class1
    Public Shared Property Frm As Form1
End Class
```

You'd just do, in Form1:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Class1.Frm = Me
End Sub
```

Now Class1 has the correct reference to the instance of Form1 that was actually displayed on the screen and it can access all the members of it, such as:

```
' ... in Class1 ...
Frm.Label1.Text = "Hello from Class1"
```

You don't need a separate shared variable for Label1 above to be able to access it.